# How to raise up old post to the top in the friends time line in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I post something on Facebook, it is automatically seen in my friends timeline. But after some time post goes down in the timeline. So I want to know if it is possible to do that for example twice a week this post automatically
raise up to the top in the friends time line?

Can it be done using Facebook API or with the help of personal settings?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to push a post's place in the News Feed via the API or any setting.

Comment: Any idea how can I do it?